# jQuery.eCalendar() - only display events onclick on date

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am trying to create an eCalendar to only display the events for the day when click on it. Is it possible to do so? I would be thankful for any help.

**Here is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').eCalendar({

    weekDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    textArrows: {
      previous: '<',
      next: '>'
    },
    eventTitle: 'Events',
    url: '',
    events: [{
      title: 'Event 1',
      description: 'Description 1',
      datetime: new Date(2019, 8, 15, 17)
    }, {
      title: 'Event 2',
      description: 'Description 2',
      datetime: new Date(2019, 9, 14, 16)
    }, {
      title: 'Event 3',
      description: 'jQueryScript.Net',
      datetime: new Date(2019, 9, 10, 16)
    }]
  });
});
```

**Here is the example of the code:**

https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Create-A-Simple-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery-e-calendar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the library by adding a click event.

Here's what I added to the library.
First, I created a click event :

```
    //Add click event for each day with events on calender
    var mouseClickEvent = function () {
        $(".c-event-item").hide();
        var d = $(this).attr('data-event-day');
                $('div.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').show();
        $('div.c-event-item[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').show();
    };
```

on the print(), register the mouseClickEvent for each days.

```
if (d.getDate() == day && (d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear) {
    cDay.addClass('c-event').attr('data-event-day', d.getDate());
    cDay.on('mouseover', mouseOverEvent).on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveEvent);
    //register the click events
    cDay.on('mousedown', mouseClickEvent)
}
```

Also, don't forget that you need to hide the event list by default by adding this code on print()

```
//hide the eventlist by default
item.attr('style', 'display:none');
```

You can check my modification here :
https://jsfiddle.net/cuaowret/